# Trigger problems in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I've been trying to get a trigger that will essentially run a constraint like this;
CONSTRAINT (Date <= Meeting.EndDate)

Where it will compare the Date stated in one table (Race) with the Date stated in another table (Meeting). I know I could achieve this using foreign keys but I'm pretty sure to get more marks I need to use a trigger.

So far I've got this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER race_date_trg    
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON RACE
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    MEETING_ENDDATE DATE;
    STARTDATE race.racedate%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT ENDDATE INTO MEETING_ENDDATE FROM meeting;
    IF STARTDATE > MEETING_ENDDATE THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Wrong start date!');
    END IF;
  end race_date_trg;
```

It compiles fine, but when I try and populate my tables with something that will raise the error, I'm getting this:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table SE488.MEETING is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SE488.RACE_DATE_TRG", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SE488.RACE_DATE_TRG'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Thanks for the help.

Creation of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Meeting
(
MeetLocation varchar2(60),
StartDate date,
EndDate date,
MeetName varchar2(60)
);

CREATE TABLE Race
(
RaceID NUMBER,
RaceLocation varchar2(60),
MeetingStart date,
RaceDate date,
RaceTime timestamp(0), 
RaceName varchar2(60),
RaceType varchar2(8),
MinAge numeric(2),
MaxAge numeric(2),
Sex varchar2(2) NULL
);
```

Populating them:

```
  INTO Meeting (MeetLocation,StartDate,EndDate,MeetName)
    values('Talbot','30-Jul-05','07-Aug-05','Midlands Derby')
  INTO Meeting (MeetLocation,StartDate,EndDate,MeetName)
    values('Ascot','04-Jul-10','07-Aug-10','National Derby')

  INTO Race (RaceID,RaceLocation,MeetingStart,RaceDate,RaceTime,RaceName,RaceType,MinAge,MaxAge,Sex)
    values('1','Talbot','20-Jul-05','31-Jul-05',to_date('2005/07/31:12:00:00PM', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:sspm'),'600m Dash','Flat','2','10','M')
  INTO Race (RaceID,RaceLocation,MeetingStart,RaceDate,RaceTime,RaceName,RaceType,MinAge,MaxAge,Sex)
    values('2','Talbot','30-Jul-05','01-Aug-05',to_date('2005/08/01:01:10:00PM', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:sspm'),'1km Hurdles','Flat','6','12','F')
```

Comment: Is the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on `race` coming from another trigger defined on the `MEETING` table?

Comment: Mihai, I also had the same error using BEFORE.
@JustinCave, I don't think so - this is my only trigger.

Comment: Post a reproducible test case.  Post the DDL to create the two tables.  Post the DML to populate the tables if that data is needed to reproduce the problem.  Post the statement that you're using that causes the trigger to fire.

Comment: I think you may have just pointed out the problem. I don't actually have a statement that causes the trigger to fire? (I wasn't aware that I needed one). 

Where would something like this go?

Comment: You must have a statement that causes the trigger to fire.  Some `insert` or `update` statement on `race` is being executed that is causing the trigger to fire.  I'd guess that that statement is coming from a trigger on `meeting` but that's why I'm asking for a reproducible test case.

Comment: I've posted the create and populate code.

Comment: @Naffel - there is something missing, the code you've provided won't give that error. Query `user_triggers`, and/or `user_objects`, to see if there's something there you'd forgotten about. Maybe a trigger you created for an earlier attempt?

Comment: How/Where would I do this? Sorry, I'm completely clueless with this.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure to get more marks I need to use a trigger"  What a terrible reason for making a poor design decision.  Triggers are very rarely the right implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER race_date_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RACE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    meet_date date;
    start_date date := :new.RaceDate;
BEGIN
    SELECT StartDate INTO meet_date FROM meeting WHERE MeetLocation = :new.RaceLocation;
    IF start_date > meet_date THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Wrong start date!');
    END IF;
END race_date_trg;
/
```

I Think you want raise error or exception. When someone insert or update table race, If start date (from table race) is lower than meet date (from table meeting).
:D

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, even when the data shouldn't bring up the error. :/

Comment: did you remove old trigger? you must remove old trigger first. :D